# Universal templated setter

Tags: c++, templates

In our program, we would like to use a templated function for setting all the members. Every member has an associated enum, which is also used in other parts of this class. Here is the class:

```
class MyClass {
public:
    // Set function here

private:
    std::string _name;
    unsigned _capacity, _computers;
}
```

Ideal solution that we would like to use, would look something like this:

```
template<Trait trait, typename Value>
void set(Value&& val) {
    switch (trait) {
    case Trait::name:
        _name = std::forward<Value>(val);
        break;
    case Trait::capacity:
        _capacity = std::forward<Value>(val);
        break;
    case Trait::computers:
        _computers = std::forward<Value>(val);
        break;
    }
}
```

And would be called like this:

```
MyClass a;
a.set<Trait::name>("Name");
a.set<Trait::capacity>(100);
```

Closest to to this, we've got are multiple specializations by type of the trait:

```
template<Trait trait>
void set(unsigned val) {
    switch (trait) {
    case Trait::capacity:
        _capacity = val;
        break;
    case Trait::computers:
        _computers = val;
        break;
    default:
        throw std::logic_error("Can't set this");
    }
}
```

Although this is working, it would be nicer to use single function templated by value. The error we were getting was that in switch statement compiler cannot convert from const char* to unsigned even though it should never get to that statement.

It would be possible to write with constexpr if, but we most probably can't use it (VS17).

Can it be implemented in a single setter, templated by the trait to use and its type?

Comment: Without constexpr if, the compiler will still need to compile all branches in an if statement, so the code needs to be valid for all types. You'll need to write a  template specialization for each Trait, or use tagged dispatch.

Comment: Isn't there some other option than switch/if that would be constexpr and allow for this single method to work?

Comment: Unfortunately not. You need to call a different function per type here.

Comment: So instead of three one-line setters, you now have half a page of code and an enum to sync. What's the advantage?